# I started a bounty, and found the answer myself

Tags: support

I started a bounty [thunar-volman-automount-and-autoplay-not-longer-working-dvd-cd-only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355259/thunar-volman-automount-and-autoplay-not-longer-working-dvd-cd-only)

And found the Solution myself after 2 days. Now I should give someone the bounty, but there is only my answer. So please: what to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't award bounties to your own answers anymore (you used to be able to, but even then you got no reputation for it). If there are no other answers there's nothing you can do with it; it will expire automatically without being awarded.